# fortran, read command

Tags: fortran90

I have a .dat file that I want to read with a program in Fortran 90. The data file contains only one very long column of complex numbers. My problem is that I want to read only one part of the column, e.g., only from the nth up to the mth element including, and create an one-dimensional array from it. However, if I write something like

```
open(unit = 100, file = 'datafile.dat', status = 'old', action = 'read')
do j = n,m
       read(100,*) vec(j-n+1)
    end do
close(100)
```

the program reads the first m-n+1 elements from my file and not the ones from n to m including. Is there any way to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is an obvious solution - you can simply execute `n-1` dummy reads before reading actual data:

```
open(unit = 100, file = 'datafile.dat', status = 'old', action = 'read')
do j = 1,n-1
   read(100,*)
end do
do j = n,m
   read(100,*) vec(j-n+1)
end do
close(100)
```

You can also use the `/` edit descriptor and condense the first loop into a single read statement:

```
nm2 = n-2
read(100,'(<nm2>/)')
do j = n,m
   read(100,*) vec(j-n+1)
end do
```

(this is `n-2` records are being skipped because of the `<nm2>/` edit descriptor and one record is skipped by the dummy read)

With compilers that do not support the `<x>` format extension, you can construct the format descriptor in an internal file:

```
character(len=20) :: fmt

write(fmt, "('(',I0,'/)')") n-2
read(100,fmt)
do j = n,m
   read(100,*) vec(j-n+1)
end do
```